# return self.browse((self._ids[key],)) IndexError: tuple index out of range : When sending message from Discuss in Odoo V13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-13

Below error occur, whenever sending a message on discuss module, which we configured to send notifications to users firebase_id.

```py
File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/models/mail_channel.py", line 368, in message_post
    message = super(Channel, self.with_context(mail_create_nosubscribe=True)).message_post(message_type=message_type, moderation_status=moderation_status, **kwargs)**
File "/odoo/custom/addons/elite_event_management_api/controllers/message.py", line 34, in message_post
    registration_id = channel_partner_id.partner_id.user_ids[0].firebase_id
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 5624, in _getitem_
    return self.browse((self._ids[key],))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

HERE IS THE CODE -All users are unable to send messages on discuss Module.

```
import logging
from odoo import models, api
from odoo.exceptions import AccessDenied, UserError
logger = logging.getLogger(__name_)
class MailThred(models.AbstractModel):
    _inherit = "mail.thread"

    @api.returns('mail.message', lambda value: value.id)
    def message_post(self, *,
                     body='', subject=None, message_type='notification',
                     email_from=None, author_id=None, parent_id=False,
                     subtype_id=False, subtype=None, partner_ids=None, channel_ids=None,
                     attachments=None, attachment_ids=None,
                     add_sign=True, record_name=False,
                     **kwargs):

        res = super(MailThred, self).message_post(body=body, subject=subject, message_type=message_type,
                     email_from=email_from, author_id=author_id, parent_id=parent_id,
                     subtype_id=subtype_id, subtype=subtype, partner_ids=partner_ids, channel_ids=channel_ids,
                     attachments=attachments, attachment_ids=attachment_ids,
                     add_sign=add_sign, record_name=record_name,
                     **kwargs)
        message_subtype_id = self.env['mail.message.subtype'].sudo().search([('name', 'ilike', 'Discussions')])
        if res.message_type == 'comment' and res.subtype_id.id == message_subtype_id.id:
            for each in res.channel_ids:
                for channel_partner_id in each.channel_last_seen_partner_ids:
                    if channel_partner_id.partner_id.id != res.author_id.id:
                        from . import FCMManager as fcm
                        registration_id = channel_partner_id.partner_id.user_ids[0].firebase_id
                        if registration_id:
                            try:
                                tokens = [str(registration_id)]
                                message_title = "ControlE@ERP - CHAT"
                                message_body = res.body
                                fcm.sendPush(message_title, message_body, tokens)
                                _logger.info('ControlE@ERP Alert- NEW CHAT MESSAGE SENT')
                            except Exception as e:
                                _logger.info('not sent')
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no users in channel_partner_id.partner_id.user_ids, so you are trying to get the 0th element from empty list ,
So check your code and try again.

Comment: Thanks, but this happens whenever i send message into discuss in odoo ERP. We added a file message.py in which we added code to send messages also to firebase_id.

Comment: Thanks, but this happens whenever i send message into discuss in odoo ERP. We added code in a file message.py (which tell to discuss app, whenever any message sending to users in the channel, same notification has to be sent to there firebase id, which are stored into our user setting page )

Comment: Than It may be possible that all the partners doesn't have users, so all you need is one condition that can check if there is user_id than fetch firebase_id from it otherwise not.